# Remove/Rename Special Character while creating column name using AWS Glue Crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-glue

I am crawling an S3 bucket using AWS Glue Crawler which creates table schema in Athena.

I understand Athena does not support column names which have special characters like \ (backward slash) etc.

Is there a way which can exclude/rename these column names while the crawler is crawling from the S3 bucket?

I have a few columns names like (RelatedAWSResources:0/name) which give me an error when I query them in Athena.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Marcin : What is the ideal way of doing this ? Removing special character in Glue ETL job or removing it in data transformation in Kinesis firehose using lamda ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, there is no such way. What you could probably do is to setup **AWS Glue Job**, and transform all your data to a format that is suitable for Athena.

Comment: After Glue crawler has crawled the data from S3 bucket, is it possible to write AWS Glue job to convert multiline json to single line json using python script in the job as AWS Athena expects json data to be in single line ?

Comment: @user662285 Yes, you can program whatever you want with AWS Glue jobs.

Comment: @user662285 I would suggest making a new question for that with relevant details and examples.